# How to use char data type as a number rather than a character?

Tags: c++, char, int, byte

When I use the `char` datatype to add two numbers, I get the sum of the ASCII code of the characters and not the numbers itself. When I researched on the internet, various sites say that the `char` type can indeed be used to handle one byte numbers. But in reality, I get the sum of ASCII values. Why is this happening? Below is just a sample code which illustrates the problem:

```
uint8_t rows,cols; //uint8_t is just a typedef for char
cin >> rows;
cout << rows + 1 << endl;
```

Comment: "not the numbers itself". What exactly do you mean by this? Do you mean where A would equal 1 and B would equal 2? Could you please elaborate a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When people talk about "one-byte numbers", they're talking about 8-bit values, ranging from -128 to 127 for a `char`, or 0 to 255 for an `unsigned char`, also known as *octets*. These can be converted directly to larger integer types and to floats:

```
char eight_bit = 122;
float floating_point = eight_bit; // = 122.0
```

If you're trying to convert a digit value such as `'1'` into the numeric value it represents, there's `stoi`:

```
#include <string>

int ctoi(char c) {
    std::string temp;
    temp.push_back(c);
    return std::stoi(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chars store the ASCII equivalent of a character as an integer.

For example

```
char value = 'A' // == int 65
```

It's best you use a short integer to store numbers, but if you really want to, you can do something like this;

```
char value1 = '2';
char value2 = '5';
char sum = (value1 + value2) - '0'; // int value of sum would be 7
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `char`, you use signed 8 bit data type (mostly).

And you get "sum of ASCII" only because `std::cout` is programmed to display `char` as ASCII character.

Try

```
cout << stratic_cast<int16_t>(rows) + 1 << endl;
```

And you will see that you get the 'number' rather than an 'ASCII character'.

*NOTE*

`uint8_t` is not (or probably should not be) `char` since `char` is defined as **signed** data type while `uint*` stands for **unsigned**.